# How do I prevent a variable from getting lost in Python after I render an HTML template and call a Post method from the HTML template?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm in the process of building my first web application in python using flask and every step of the way is essentially a new lesson for me.  All of my coding experience is in Visual Basic and vb.Net, so this is still all quite new for me.

What I am trying to do is actually incredibly simple, but I am struggling with a way to do it, let alone determine the best way to do it.  Also, forgive me if my python/flask vocabulary is wrong.. I don't quite speak "the language".

I have a views.route for a journal entry which renders an html template where the user can make a journal entry.  On this template, there is also date Picker and I am grabbing the date from that template.  I want to send that in the redirect to the next page, which is a survey.

```
return redirect(url_for('views.survey', date = date))
```

I grab the date parameter using the request.args

```
   form = Survey1Form(request.form)
   date = request.args['date'] #grabbing the date parameter from the redirect in Journal above.
   return render_template('survey.html',date = date, form = form,user = current_user)
```

Survey.html is a survey where the user fills out some fields.  clicking submit fires a post method which triggers the first part of the if statement, evaluating for a post method.

```
def survey():
    if request.method == "POST":
        energy = request.form.get('Energy')
        mood= request.form.get('Mood')
        symptom= request.form.get('Symptom')
        overall = request.form.get('Overall')
        #need to validate if they have already done survey for that date
        new_survey = tbl_survey(user_id=current_user.id,date = date, energy = energy, mood = mood, symptom = symptom, overall = overall )
        db.session.add(new_survey)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your responses were recorded!', category = 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
    else:
        form = Survey1Form(request.form)
        date = request.args['date'] #grabbing the date parameter from the redirect in Journal above.
        return render_template('survey.html',date = date, form = form,user = current_user)
```

My question is simple, how can I maintain that date value/variable.  What is the best way to store it.  I have tried a class with a getter/setter but it still gets reset when I submit the survey and redirect back to this block of code above. Want to avoid a global variable and tbh, I can't get that quite right either.  Can I pass the date value through the html and back to the python code?  Or am I missing something very simple and obvious.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have two options for preserving the date. So the problem could be solved if you restructure your code.

So you pass on the selected date with a redirect. In my example I use the isoformat for a timestamp.

```py
@views.route('/somewhere')
def somewhere():
    dt = datetime.now() 
    return redirect(url_for('views.survey', date=dt.isoformat()))
```

The first option is to constantly pass the date within the URL parameters. It is necessary to leave the action parameter within the form empty or to pass on the date using `url_for` as usual.
However, the query of `request.args` should go to the beginning of the endpoint before the if-condition.

```py
@views.route('/survey', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def survey():
    dt = request.args.get('date', datetime.now(), type=datetime.fromisoformat)
    form = SurveyForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit(): # It is a POST request and all inputs are valid.
        print(dt)
    return render_template('survey.html', **locals())
```

Since you're already using this type of functionality to pass the date between endpoints, it seems the most appropriate to me.

The second option is to pass the date to a hidden input field. It remains in this field until it can be checked and used.

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import DateTimeField, StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.widgets import HiddenInput

# ...

class SurveyForm(FlaskForm):
    date = DateTimeField(
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        widget=HiddenInput()
    )
    # ...

@views.route('/survey', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def survey():
    dt = request.args.get('date', datetime.now(), type=datetime.fromisoformat)
    form = SurveyForm(request.form, date=dt)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.date.data)
    return render_template('survey.html', **locals())
```

In this case, you no longer need to pass the date within the URL. So you can also reset the action parameter with `url_for('views.survey')` and omit the url parameter. The date in the input field is retained.

```html
<form action="{{url_for('survey')}}" method="post">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {# additional fields here #}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Using the first variant, your code might look something like this, depending on which notations you prefer.

```py
def survey():
    dt = request.args.get('date') # Optionally convert the date to an object here.
    form = SurveyForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Possibly check the date here.
        new_survey = Survey(user_id=current_user.id, date=dt)
        form.populate_obj(new_survey) # Transfer the form data to the object.
        db.session.add(new_survey)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your responses were recorded!', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
    return render_template('survey.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work with the second option.  I would have preferred the first option and I did try that more or less, but every time I render the html template and submit and fire the post event, dt=request.args.get('date') gets set to none and I lose the date.  I don't understand why this happens and the way I have to troubleshoot it makes my code very messy.  But yes, I did get it to work with the hidden field.  So thanks..